# Phrets is giving Invalid Type error using getobject

Tags: php, phrets

can any one help me how to get images of property using reso phrets.

Below is my code which is executing :

```
$rets   = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
$search = $rets->Search("Property","Residential","*",
    array( 
        'QueryType'           => 'DMQL2',
        "Count"               => 1,
        "Format"              => "COMPACT-DECODED",
        "Limit"               => 5,
        "Offset"              => 0,
        "Select"              => "ListingKeyNumeric,BuyerAgentLastName,buyerAgentFirstName,buyerOfficeName,City,Country,CurrentPrice,StreetName,PostalCode,StateOrProvince,StreetNumberNumeric,BedroomsTotal,BathroomsTotalInteger,LotSizeSquareFeet,YearBuilt,StandardStatus,LotSizeAcres,ListOfficeMlsId,ListPrice,BathroomsFull,BathroomsHalf,PropertySubType,ArchitecturalStyle,MLSAreaMajor,CountyOrParish,Utilities,ParkingTotal,ParkingFeatures,GarageSpaces,View,PoolPrivateYN,PoolFeatures,InteriorFeatures,Appliances,Heating,Cooling,FireplaceYN,FireplaceFeatures,StoriesTotal,ExteriorFeatures,LotSizeDimensions,WindowFeatures,Roof,ConstructionMaterials,FoundationDetails,HighSchoolDistrict,ElementarySchool,MiddleOrJuniorSchool,OriginalEntryTimestamp,DaysOnMarket,Zoning,AssociationFee,AssociationFeeFrequency,ListOfficeName,PricePerSquareFoot,ListAgentFirstName,ListAgentLastName,ListAgentMlsId,InternetAddressDisplayYN,ListingId,PhotosCount",
        "RestrictedIndicator" => "****",
        "StandardNames"       => 1 
    )
);

foreach ($search as $r) {

    $rets_resource = 'Property';
    $object_type   = 'photo';
    $listing_id    = $r['ListingId'];
    $photos        = $rets->GetObject('Property',$classes->first()->getClassName(),'OC17206923,217009806DA,PW17081942','*',0);
    print_r($photos);
}
```

**Result What i am getting :**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(    [items:protected] => Array
    (
      [0] => PHRETS\Models\Object Object
      (
       [content_type:protected] => text/xml
       [content_id:protected] => 
       [object_id:protected] => 
       [mime_version:protected] => 1.0
       [location:protected] => 
       [content_description:protected] => 
       [content_sub_description:protected] => 
       [content:protected] => 

       [preferred:protected] => 
       [error:protected] => PHRETS\Models\RETSError Object
      (
        [code:protected] => 20401
        [message:protected] => Invalid Type
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of **$classes->first()->getClassName()** for the type parameter in the getObject() call?

Maybe you want to use 'photo' or $object_type instead?

Answer (score 0):

Second param given to the getObject() method is wrong. You are trying to give the class name, instead object type.

Check this phrets [getObject()](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetObject) documentation for reference.

Need to change your code like this,

```
$photos        = $rets->GetObject('Property',$object_type,'OC17206923,217009806DA,PW17081942','*',0);
```

Also you can change the last param with "1" to get the image url alone. This option may not be supported by all MLSs.